# What is the difference between Angular 2 Components and Web Components?

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm very confused. Can an Angular 2 Component be reused outside of the Angular scope just like a Web Component?

Or maybe it's more than that?

Comment: Erf, actually the other question is a duplicate of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention was to make Angular components reusable Web components like Polymer elements and it was communicated this way a while back.

Currently support for this is only very limited. Each Angular root component (the outer-most Angular component) is a distinct Angular application and the root component is quite limited.

- `@Input()` doesn't read attribute values while it does inside another Angular component
- `@Attribute()` annotation for a constructor argument doesn't inject the attribute value like it does when used inside another Angular2 component
- transclusion doesn't work `<ng-content>` to wrap existing HTML with an Angular component
- Each root component has its own injector for dependency injection.

This might be an open task for later but there is currently no concrete information available as far as I know.