# are angular components the same as custom elements (from web components technology)?

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element

I am looking at angular 4.0 and I have done a bit of Web components with Polymer. Angular components and custom elements in Polymer look the same from use case point of view. The angular components also provide some framework specific lifecycle callbacks.

What are the difference if any ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relation between Angular components and web components. Angular components are only reusable in other Angular components.

There is an ongoing effort (currently only experimental) to change that - Angular elements https://moduscreate.com/blog/angular-elements-ngcomponents-everywhere/

See also

- [Does Angular2 use Web Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226449/does-angular2-use-web-components/40231867#40231867)
- [What is the difference between Angular 2 Components and Web Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182420/what-is-the-difference-between-angular-2-components-and-web-components/36182559#36182559)
- [How can I convert angular 2 components to webcomponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36929447/how-can-i-convert-angular-2-components-to-webcomponents/36930098#36930098)
- [WebComponent implementation in Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039069/webcomponent-implementation-in-angular-2/45039099#45039099)

Comment: so if I understand correctly, when all browsers start supporting web components natively, angular components wont be needed. The angular library might still be used for other things.

Comment: No, as I said, Angular components and web components are not related. When web components are fully supported everywhere, Angular components will switch to native shadow DOM and then Angulars emulation of the shadow DOM will become obsolete.